# Change AJAX filter from POST to GET for URL Parameters

Tags: wp-query, filters, ajax, jquery

I have a well defined AJAX filter, in two parts, one for a load more button, and one for a selection of drop down filters.  Both reload a list of properties on the front-end in AJAX, and work together in unison (e.g. If I select Min price, max price and number of beds in dropdowns, the list refreshes, and the load more button works as it should).

However, I want to enhance this, so that it also pushes a parameter into the URL, and get the AJAX to look at that parameter instead.  So for example, if I select from the dropdown, min price: 100000, max price 5000000 and beds 3, the AJax runs as normal, but the URL also changes to:

```
mydomain.com/?min_price=100000&max_price=5000000&beds=3
```

In turn, this URL could be entered directly, and the filters would be preselected, both in the dropdown, and in the AJAX call.

Here's my code:

JS:

```
jQuery(function($){


 // AJAX Stuff for filters + load more button

/*
 * Load More
 */
$('#prop_loadmore').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url : prop_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, 
        data : {
            'action': 'loadmorebutton',
            'query': prop_loadmore_params.posts, // loop parameters passed by wp_localize_script()
            'page' : prop_loadmore_params.current_page, // Get the current page

        },
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
            $('#prop_loadmore').text( 'Loading...' ); 
            $('#prop_loadmore').addClass( 'loading' );

        },
        success : function( posts ){
            if( posts ) {
                $('#prop_loadmore').removeClass( 'loading' );
                $('#prop_loadmore').text( 'More Listings' );
                $('#main_posts').append( posts ); 
            //    $(".price-txt").digits(); // Add the commas!
                localStorage.setItem("posts", posts);
                prop_loadmore_params.current_page++; // Increase current page by 1

                var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
                params.set('page', prop_loadmore_params.current_page);
                window.history.replaceState({}, "", decodeURIComponent(`${location.pathname}?${params}`));


                if ( prop_loadmore_params.current_page == prop_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                    $('#prop_loadmore').hide(); // if last page, hide loadmore

            } else {
                $('#prop_loadmore').hide(); // if no properties, hide loadmore
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});

/*
 * Filter
 */
$('#filter').change(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

    $.ajax({
        url : prop_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
        data : $('#filter').serialize(), 
        dataType : 'json',

        success : function( data ){

            // reset current page to 1 when filters on
            prop_loadmore_params.current_page = 1;

            prop_loadmore_params.posts = data.posts;

            // set max page
            prop_loadmore_params.max_page = data.max_page;

            found_posts = data.found_posts 

            //First pull out the empty strings

            var formData = $('#filter').serializeArray().filter(function (i) {
                if(i.value != 'prop_filters') {
                    return i.value;
                }
            });

            //Now push formData to URL
            window.history.pushState('', 'title', '?' + $.param(formData) + '&page=' + prop_loadmore_params.current_page);

            $('#main_posts').html(data.content);
            $('.listings-count').text( found_posts + ' Real Estate Listings for Sale' );


            if (found_posts > 9) {
                $('#prop_loadmore').show();
            }
             if ( prop_loadmore_params.current_page == prop_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                    $('#prop_loadmore').hide(); // if last page, hide loadmore




            // If not enough posts for 2nd page, hide loadmore
            if ( data.max_page < 2 ) {
                $('#prop_loadmore').hide();
            } else {
                $('#prop_loadmore').show();
            }
        }
    });

    return false;

});

});
```

Functions.php :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'properties_script_and_styles');

function properties_script_and_styles() {
global $wp_query;

wp_register_script( 'property_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/properties.js', array('jquery') );


$the_page = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;

if (!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $the_page = $_GET['page'];
}

wp_localize_script( 'property_scripts', 'prop_loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
    'posts' => $wp_query->query_vars,
    'current_page' => $the_page,
    'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'found_posts' => $wp_query->found_posts,

) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'property_scripts' );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmorebutton', 'prop_loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmorebutton', 'prop_loadmore_ajax_handler');

function prop_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

$args = json_decode(  $_POST['query'] ); 
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; 
 if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
}
else {
    $args['post_status'] = array('publish', 'private');
}
query_posts( $args );

if( have_posts() ) :


    while( have_posts() ): the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile;
endif;
die;
}


function prepare_property_filters(array $args): array {

/** Price Args**/

if (!empty($_REQUEST['price_min']) || !empty($_REQUEST['price_max'])) 
{
    $args['meta_query'] = ['relation'=>'AND'];
}

// If Both
if( !empty( $_REQUEST['price_min'] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST['price_max'] )) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'price',
        'value' => array( $_REQUEST['price_min'], 
$_REQUEST['price_max'] ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'between'
    );
} else {
    // if only min price
    if( !empty( $_REQUEST['price_min'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => $_REQUEST['price_min'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>'
        );
    }
}

    // if only max price
    if( !empty( $_REQUEST['price_max'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => $_REQUEST['price_max'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        );
    }

//* 
// Bedrooms Arg
//*
    if( !empty( $_REQUEST['beds'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'bedrooms',
            'value' => $_REQUEST['beds'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        );
    }

//* 
// Property Type Arg
//*
    if( !empty( $_REQUEST['type'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'property_type',
            'value' => $_REQUEST['type'],
            'compare' => 'IN'
        );
    }

return $args;
}


add_action('wp_ajax_prop_filters', 'property_filters'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_prop_filters', 'property_filters');

function property_filters() {
//*
// Sort by Args
//*

    if( $_REQUEST['sort_by'] === 'price-desc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'DESC';
        $meta_key = 'price';
    }

    elseif( $_REQUEST['sort_by'] === 'price-asc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'ASC';
        $meta_key = 'price';
    }
    elseif( $_REQUEST['sort_by'] === 'bedrooms-desc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'DESC';
        $meta_key = 'bedrooms';
    }
    elseif( $_REQUEST["sort_by"] === 'bedrooms-asc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'ASC';
        $meta_key = 'bedrooms';
    }
    else {
        $orderby = 'date'; 
        $order = 'DESC';
        $meta_key = '';
    }
$args = prepare_property_filters([
    'posts_per_page' => 9, 
    'post_status' => is_user_logged_in() ? ['publish', 'private'] : ['publish'],
    'paged' => $_POST['page'],
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
]);
query_posts( $args );

    global $wp_query;

    if( have_posts() ) :

        ob_start();

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

        $posts_html = ob_get_contents(); 
        ob_end_clean(); 
    else:
        $posts_html = '<p>Nothing found for your criteria.</p>';
    endif;

    echo json_encode( array(
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ),
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'found_posts' => $wp_query->found_posts,
        'content' => $posts_html,
    ) );

    die();
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<input id="filter_toggle"  type="checkbox">
<?php //We need to save the varaibles in arrays, so we can then check them against the URL and populate the dropdowns

$price_min = [
'' => 'Any Price',
'100000' => '$100,000',
'150000' => '$150,000',
'200000' => '$200,000',
'250000' => '$250,000',
//etc
];

$price_max = [
'' => 'Any Price',
'100000' => '$100,000',
'150000' => '$150,000',
'200000' => '$200,000',
'250000' => '$250,000',
//etc
];

$beds = [
'' => 'All Beds',
'1' => '1+',
'2' => '2+',
'3' => '3+',
'4' => '4+',
'5' => '5+'
];

$property_type = [
'' => 'All Property Types',
'single-family-home' => 'Single Family Home',
'condo' => 'Condo',
'land' => 'Land',
'townhouse' => 'Townhouse'
];

$sort_by = [
'newest' => 'Sort by Newest',
'price-desc' => 'Sort by Price (High to Low)',
'price-asc' => 'Sort by Price (Low to High)',
'bedrooms-desc' => 'Sort by Beds (Most to Least)',
'bedrooms-asc' => 'Sort by Beds (Least to Most)'
];
?>

<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
<div class="filters_options">

  <select name="price_min" class="min_max_select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="" value="">Minimum Price</option>
    <?php foreach ($price_min as $key => $value) {
         $selected = '';
         if ($_GET['price_min'] == $key) {
             $selected = ' selected="selected"';
         }
         printf(
             '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
             $key,
             $selected,
             $value
         );
     } ?>
  </select>

  <select name="price_max" class="min_max_select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Maximum Price</option>
    <?php foreach ($price_max as $key => $value) {
         $selected = '';
         if ($_GET['price_max'] == $key) {
             $selected = ' selected="selected"';
         }
         printf(
             '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
             $key,
             $selected,
             $value
         );
     } ?>
  </select>

  <select name="beds" class="select_beds">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Bedrooms</option>
    <?php foreach ($beds as $key => $value) {
         $selected = '';
         if ($_GET['beds'] == $key) {
             $selected = ' selected="selected"';
         }
         printf(
             '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
             $key,
             $selected,
             $value
         );
     } ?>
  </select>

  <!-- <select>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Bathrooms</option>
    <option value="">All Baths</option>
    <option value="1+">1+</option>
    <option value="1+">2+</option>
    <option value="1+">3+</option>
    <option value="1+">4+</option>
    <option value="1+">5+</option>
  </select> -->

  <select name="type" class="sort_by_property_type">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Property Type</option>
    <?php foreach ($property_type as $key => $value) {
         $selected = '';
         if ($_GET['type'] == $key) {
             $selected = ' selected="selected"';
         }
         printf(
             '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
             $key,
             $selected,
             $value
         );
     } ?>
  </select>

  <!-- <select>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Property View</option>
    <option value="">All Property Views</option>
    <option value="Golf View">Golf View</option>
    <option value="Ocean View">Ocean View</option>
    <option value="Ocean Front">Ocean Front</option>
  </select> -->

  <select name="sort_by" class="sort_by_dropdown">
    <?php
     foreach ($sort_by as $key => $value) {
         $selected = '';
         if ($_GET['sort_by'] == $key) {
             $selected = ' selected="selected"';
         }
         printf(
             '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
             $key,
             $selected,
             $value
         );
     }
     ?>
  </select>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="prop_filters" />
</div>

 <span class="reset_btn reset">reset</span>
<label class="done_btn" for="filter_toggle">Done</label>
</form> 
</div>

<ul id="main_posts" class="item-listings">
<?php 

//*
// Sort by Args
//*

    if( $_GET['sort_by'] === 'price-desc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'DESC';
        $meta_key = 'price';
    }

    elseif( $_GET['sort_by'] === 'price-asc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'ASC';
        $meta_key = 'price';
    }
    elseif( $_GET['sort_by'] === 'bedrooms-desc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'DESC';
        $meta_key = 'bedrooms';
    }
    elseif( $_GET["sort_by"] === 'bedrooms-asc' ) {
        $orderby = 'meta_value_num'; 
        $order = 'ASC';
        $meta_key = 'bedrooms';
    }
    else {
        $orderby = 'date'; 
        $order = 'DESC';
        $meta_key = '';
    }

    $per_page = 9;

    if(!empty( $_GET['page'])) {
        $per_page = $_GET['page'] * 9;
    }

// Build the inital Loop
$args = prepare_property_filters([
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'paged' => $_POST['page'],
    'meta_key' => $meta_key,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
]);

query_posts($args);

if( have_posts() ) :

    while( have_posts() ): the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

        $count_posts = $wp_query->found_posts; 

    endwhile;
endif;

?>
</ul>


<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
    echo '<div id="prop_loadmore">More Listings</div>';
endif;?>

<span class="listings-count"><?php echo $count_posts;?> Real Estate Listings for Sale</span>
<!-- <span class="reset">reset</span> -->
```

EDIT:  Removed the load more code, as it's not relevant here.

EDIT2:  Added Pagination back in as it IS relevant...

EDIT3:  I am SUPER close to getting this working.  I have updated the code above.  The ONLY thing that is not working is the Load More pagination button, when loaded direct from a URL (e.g. refreshing the page with parameters set).  If I load the URL as:

mydomain.com/?min_price=100000&max_price=5000000&beds=3?page=3

It will load all the properties correctly, including showing 3 pages of properties immediately.  On click of Load More Button, it changes ?page=3 to ?page=4 HOWEVER it appends an **unfiltered** set of properties... For some reason on load of the page, the parameters are not saving into the args that loadmore button runs on click.

Comment: Is the "load more" part relevant here? (If not, could you remove these parts, right now that is quite a wall of code.)

Comment: I figured it was, as the load more is combined with the AJAX filters (e.g. it has to 'load more' the already filtered content)...  But thinking about it, you may be right!

Answer (score 1):

I would divide your question into two parts:

1. Use the query parameters as default for the filter on page load.
2. Update the query parameters dynamically when the form values change.

To achieve 1. you'll first need to extract the logic to build `$args` in `property_filters()` so it can be used on the initial load:

```
function prepare_property_filters(array $args): array {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['price_min']) || !empty($_REQUEST['price_max'])) {
        $args['meta_query'] = ['relation'=>'AND'];
    }
    // etc.
    return $args;
}
```

I've made some additional changes to your code:

- Add [type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).
- Change `isset($foo) && $foo` to `!empty($foo)` which is basically the same*.
- Use [short array syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).
- Switch from `$_POST` to [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), the benefit here is that you don't have to differentiate between `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

You can use this then like so

functions.php

```
function property_filters() {
    $order = explode( '-', $_POST['sort_by_dropdown'] );

    $args = prepare_property_filters([
        'posts_per_page' => 9, 
        'post_status' => is_user_logged_in() ? ['publish', 'private'] : ['publish'],
        'paged' => $_POST['page']
    ]);
    query_posts( $args );

    global $wp_query;
    if( have_posts() ) :
       // etc.
```

HTML

```
<ul id="main_posts" class="item-listings">
<?php 
// Build the inital Loop
$args = prepare_property_filters([
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged
]);

query_posts($args);
// etc.
```

**Now on the initial page load and with the query parameters, you should see the list properly filtered.**

But the user will not have these values pre-selected, so update the form HTML like so

```
<?php
$price_min = [
    '' => 'Any Price',
    '100000' => '$100,000',
    //etc.
];
?>
<select name="price_min" class="min_max_select">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Minimum Price</option>
     <?php
     foreach ($price_min as $key => $value) {
         $selected = '';
         if (!empty($_GET[$key]) && $_GET[$key] === $value) {
             $selected = ' selected="selected"';
         }
         printf(
             '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
             $key,
             $selected,
             $value
         );
     }
     ?>
</select>
```

**Now we truly solved problem #1.** If the query parameters are present, the list will be pre-filtered and the proper filters will already be selected in the form.

---

As for problem #2, this can be boiled down to "change to new URL without reloading", which already has great answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340186). The idea usually is to use `window.history.pushState()`. (Check the [MDN docs for the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for a depper look into this.)

```
$('#filter').change(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url : prop_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
        data : $('#filter').serialize(), 
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function(xhr){
            $('#filter').find('button').text('Filtering...');
        },
        success : function( data ){
            // set HTML, variables, etc. as you currently do

            window.history.pushState($('#filter'), 'title', '?' + $('#filter').serialize());
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I'm not entirely sure, if title is used (second argument), you can probably pass it via localize as well.

This should change the URL to reflect the changed form. **And this solves problem #2.**

<sub>*technically, this is not true but in my experience, in most use cases the edge cases don't matter</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  It works nicely, BUT doesn't work with the pagination AJAX I have. (Which I removed from the initial post as someone said it wasn't relevant. I've re-edited the initial post to now include the pagination code.  How do I include this with your code above?

Comment: (It was me who presumed this :) I'll check it, but soonest tomorrow, maybe even the day after that

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help! Pagination works fine with the AJAX call if filters selected in dropdowns, but if the page is loaded via the parameters directly, the initial page is correct, but when you click "view more" button it doesn't filter them, just loads the standard set.  It also would be great to have ?page=3 or whatever hit the URL, and if the user visits the site directly with ?page=3 in the URL, then the first 3 pages of properties are already visible. Let me know if I can send you some $ for a beer or something?

Comment: Any luck with this? :)

Comment: I've updated the original post, as I'm SUPER close to having this working, just one niggle that I can't find the fix for.